# Java stop MIDI playback

Tags: java, audio, midi

Hi I have java application which plays midi messages from sequence. I'm doing this using jfugue library.

the problem is when I'm tryingto stop playback with stop button (which call sequencer.stop() and sequencer.close()) the last played note is sound all of rest time, and I can't stop it.

So I'm asking about solution about stopping all audio and MIDI too! sound playback from java application.

Notice:
If you want propose just mute volume, you need to know that I want end-use will be able to press play button again and hear the sound again, so muting volumr will be not a solution, or explain please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to call [`Player.allNotesOff()`](http://www.jfugue.org/javadoc/org/jfugue/Player.html#allNotesOff%28%29) before calling `sequencer.stop()`. Untested, so please let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: nope it doesn't. the current playing note is still sounds. very weird. ((

Answer (score 0):

When MIDI plays music, it uses a combination of NOTE_ON and NOTE_OFF events. It sounds like when you press the stop button, the sequence is stopping after a NOTE_ON event had been sent, but before a NOTE_OFF event was sent. That means the sound will continue to play indefinitely.

`Player.allNotesOff()` in JFugue makes a call to JavaSound's `allNotesOff()` method in the Channel class; this call is made for each MIDI Channel (there are 16 channels). It's unfortunate that this solution isn't working. Try calling `Player.allNotesOff()` *after* `sequencer.stop()`, see if that helps.