# Cannot stop midi sequence immediately

Tags: java, midi

I have used the same javax.sound.midi example as thequerist of question [Terminate Java Midi output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972603/terminate-java-midi-output). There the question was about terminating a sequence after playing it once instead of looping it.

I wonder how I can "inject" a command to tell the sequencer (or rather the synthesizer?) to stop playing at the push of a button.

So far I've tried closing synthesizer and sequencer, but the sound is still playing. Also neither deleting the track nor switching off all notes in the cannels (as suggested in [Java stop MIDI playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779434/java-stop-midi-playback)) worked:

```
if (synth != null) {
        javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();

        channels[0].allNotesOff();
        channels[0].allSoundOff();
    }
```

I would like to be able to play another sequence after stopping the current one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, Midi support in the Sun JRE uses a completely external (and native) midi implementation. I had a number of issues with it myself (volume control not working properly, e.g. set volume to 0 and its still audible. Sound quality is also far below what other midi players deliver). There are probably limitations in the native bindings you can't easily work around.

I solved my issues by switching to [Gervill](http://java.net/projects/gervill/downloads), a pure java implementation that was intended as a replacement of the native java midi support (there are license issues preventing the midi part to be released as open source). AFAIK they did not switch for whatever reason, but maybe they still will in a future java release.

Comment: I am using openJDK 6 (on Ubuntu 12.04) and I think the standard synthesizer there is gervill. Could it be possible that the first part of your answer is still valid in the sense that you can't control the synthesizer once a sequence is sent off?

Comment: If you use Gervill directly, the sequencer is exposed and you should be able to control it with little or no delay. Maybe the sound pipeline (after all gervill produces raw PCM) is so long you get a notable delay? When I used gervill I took the code from its sample player, so I also had control over the Line where the PCM was sent to. Still there *was* a notable delay to volume changes of about the line's buffer size. I think for minimum delays to your commands you need a small buffer size for the line *or* you need to close and reopen the line to interrupt anything currently playing.

Comment: I am not sure if the sound pipeline is the problem, but I'll follow your suggestion to look at the gervill sample player and will then tell if it worked.