# Why doesn't my MIDI program finish/close?

Tags: java, audio, exit, midi

I've got this simple program which plays just one note using MIDI. The problem is, even though it plays the note the program keeps on going, but I don't know why. Any help?

```
    Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    sequencer.open();
    Sequence sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 1);
    Track track = sequence.createTrack();

    ShortMessage noteOnMsg = new ShortMessage();
    noteOnMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 60, 100);
    ShortMessage noteOffMsg = new ShortMessage();
    noteOffMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, 60, 100);

    track.add(new MidiEvent(noteOnMsg, 0));
    track.add(new MidiEvent(noteOffMsg, 120));
    sequencer.setSequence(sequence);

    sequencer.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    sequencer.stop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sequencer needs to be closed.  One option is to just add `sequencer.close()` to the end of your code, but since Sequencer implements AutoCloseable, the better approach is to put it in a try-with-resources clause:

```
try (Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer()) {
    sequencer.open();
    Sequence sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 1);
    Track track = sequence.createTrack();

    ShortMessage noteOnMsg = new ShortMessage();
    noteOnMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 60, 100);
    ShortMessage noteOffMsg = new ShortMessage();
    noteOffMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, 60, 100);

    track.add(new MidiEvent(noteOnMsg, 0));
    track.add(new MidiEvent(noteOffMsg, 120));
    sequencer.setSequence(sequence);

    sequencer.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    sequencer.stop();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use

```
 if (sequencer != null && sequencer.isOpen()) {
  sequencer.stop();
  sequencer.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: what are you talking about?? useless junk?? you took it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779434/java-stop-midi-playback ??

Comment: Why?Did you look when u answer? :)

Comment: I see that u're looking at